# SQL: Trigger datatype Conflict between time and GETDATE()

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a trigger to set the time value of a Column of data type time() to NULL when ever it is greater than GETDATE().

I am getting an error which indicates a conflict between the columns' data type time() and GETDATE() since GETDATE() retrieves date and time.

My question is how can I get the time portion only of the GETDATE() to use it in my trigger?

Trigger Code:

```
  create trigger trig1 
  on [dbo].[Products]
  after insert
  as
  update Products
  set ParkingStartTime = null
  from Products
  join inserted i
  on i.ParkingStartTime  = Products.ParkingStartTime 
  where i.ParkingStartTime >= GETDATE();
```

Regards.

Comment: What's the exact error message?  If ParkingStartTime is a `TIME` field, then indeed there's a conflict; you'd need to `CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME)`, and that assumes that the date the customer parks is today.

Comment: @Jon of All Trades The error message is `The data types time and datetime are incompatible in the greater than or equal to operator.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on the comment, you cannot implicitly cast time to datetime - so you need to convert it manually:

```
create trigger trig1    
on [dbo].[Products]   
after insert   
as   
update Products   
set ParkingStartTime = null   
from Products   
join inserted i   
on i.ParkingStartTime  = Products.ParkingStartTime    
where i.ParkingStartTime >= CAST(GETDATE() AS time(7))
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert GetDate() to just the time component - 24Hr format.

```
SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AS time(7)) AS 'time'
```